# Setting a textbox to auto-expand based on long text

Tags: c#, asp.net

Right now I have a textbox that's 200px long.  However, on rare occasions I get a user that inputs a text string that's longer than that.

Is there any way to check the length of the string and then increase the text box's width when necessary?

This is for an Intranet app written in C#.

Comment: you can also use css, http://jsfiddle.net/sVKU8/14/

Comment: This fiddle was cool, but I didn't see how to make it into a textbox.  Everything I "fiddled" with was just hard-coded text with an output that makes it *look* like it's in a textbox, but the user can't actually edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery script that does that for you. It checks the length of the inputted text and if it is greater that X, increase the width.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 10) {
            $(this).attr("style", "width: 300px");
        }
    });
</script>
```